# Showing my location on google maps?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, geolocation, custom-controls

I take his code from [w3school](http://www.w3school.com/).
Here they show how to take the user directly to an address that has been written in the JavaScript code.
Instead of taking the user to a certain place that I have set  in the code what I want is to take the user to its current position in the map but I can find a way to do this. I have already seem the code to get the geolocation with html5 but I don't know how to put everything together to make it work.
The JavaScript code is:

```
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>

<script>
var map;
var london = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);

// Add a Home control that returns the user to London
function HomeControl(controlDiv, map) {
  controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';
  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  controlUI.style.border='1px solid';
  controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
  controlUI.title = 'Set map to London';
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);
  var controlText = document.createElement('div');
  controlText.style.fontFamily='Arial,sans-serif';
  controlText.style.fontSize='12px';
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
  controlText.style.paddingRight = '4px';
  controlText.innerHTML = '<b>Home<b>'
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

  // Setup click-event listener: simply set the map to London
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
    map.setCenter(london)
  });
}

function initialize() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googleMap');
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: london,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, myOptions); 
  // Create a DIV to hold the control and call HomeControl()
  var homeControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var homeControl = new HomeControl(homeControlDiv, map);
//  homeControlDiv.index = 1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(homeControlDiv);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

for the whole code the go to [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/googleapi/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_map_controls_custom).

In other words I want to find the user current position and show it when the user clicks on HOME.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

Comment: I know that I already used the code that they show there.....
I will rephrase myself so maybe you can understand.... 

I want that the map shows the user location when the user clicks a button

Answer (score 0):

Bro ! Its not big deal Visit http://www.map-embed.com/

- Select Your Location You want to point down
- Drag down Red Pointer to your address
- Fill The Information of your address
- Make sure that your pointer is exactly at your address.
- Click On Green Button Generate code . The Code Will Copied to your Clipboard

Past it where you want to show your map.

Comment: Bro! I don't want just to show my location I want that the map shows the location of the one who is using the map not just any location but their location....